# Bootstrap 4 col-md-4 with shadow border

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

I use this carousel:

https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/temp/3549496

[image]

As you can see, there is a border around each block.

On the first, the left shadow cannot be seen, on the third slide the right shadow cannot be seen.

When I add a `margin-left:-5px` to the right `<div class="col-md-4 clearfix d-none d-md-block">`, I can see the shadow, but that is not a nice and clean code.

**Anyone knows how I can modify the col-md-4 to show the shadow also on the left and right blocks?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `carousel-inner` takes up the width of exactly 3 cards (and the space between), hence the shadow is there but is cut off. Your `margin-left: -5px` basically adjusts this, hence it works then.

However, yes, not that good a code. Simpler option, add a very little **x-axis** padding to `carousel-inner`, like add the class `px-1` to it. The space between your cards will decrease by a pixel or 2, but your shadows will now be visible better.